# Spring boot + spring data = 404 :(

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I did my Spring Boot project and everything was fine until I started screwing spring data + hibernate. I had a lot of mistakes that I consistently rules. In the end, I managed to get rid of all the errors, but now, when I run my project, when I switch to localhost: 8080, I always see a 404 error, and in my IDE there are no errors :(.

Application :

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"Service", "repository"})
@EntityScan("DataModel")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "repository")
public class CloudliquidApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CloudliquidApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ProductService productService() {
        return new ProductServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAll() {
        return productRepository.findByName("Grape");
    }
}
```

Service(Interface):

```
public interface ProductService {
    List<Product> getAll();
}
```

Repository(Interface) :

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {
    List<Product> findByName(String name);
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;


    @RequestMapping("/try")
    @ResponseBody
    public List the(){
        System.out.println("CALLLED");
        return productService.getAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "It's a CloudLiquid";
    }
```

Error by Browser:

```
    Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Dec 02 16:18:35 MSK 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: Well, you scan the packages "Service" and "repository", but your controllers are in com.lopamoko.cloudliquid. Why dont you respect conventions, and put everything under a root package, and the main application class in that root package?

Comment: Yes!!! , migrate Controller to package controller and add to scan.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to use all these annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"Service", "repository"})
@EntityScan("DataModel")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "repository")
```

You don't need to use even `scanBasePackages = {"Service", "repository"}`. Only  `@SpringBootApplication` will handle all of these. Remove all `@Bean` from main class. 
Write service class with annotation

```
@Service
public interface ProductService {
    List<Product> getAll();
}
```

And try hitting `/` to get expected output.